# Redirecting if Login Session Expires in php

Tags: php, session

I am trying to log out when session time expires. I used this code:

**home.php**

```
session_start(); 
require_once 'class.user.php'; 
$user_home = new USER(); 
if($user_home->isLoginSessionExpired()) {
        header("Location:logout.php?session_expired=1");
    }
if(!$user_home->is_logged_in()) 
{ 
$user_home->redirect($web); 
}
```

**class.user.php**

```
public function isLoginSessionExpired() {
    $login_session_duration = 10; 
    $current_time = time(); 
    if(isset($_SESSION['loggedin_time']) and isset($_SESSION["userSession"])){  
        if(((time() - $_SESSION['loggedin_time']) > $login_session_duration)){ 
            return true; 
        } 
    }
    return false;
}

    public function is_logged_in()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['userSession']))
        {
            return true;
        }
    }public function logout()
{
    session_destroy();
    $_SESSION['userSession'] = false;
}public function login($uname,$upass)
{
    try
    {
        $stmt = $this->conn->prepare("SELECT * FROM tbl_users WHERE userName=:username");
        $stmt->execute(array(":username"=>$uname));
        $userRow=$stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

        if($stmt->rowCount() == 1)
        {
            if($userRow['userStatus']=="Y")
            {
                if($userRow['userPass']==md5($upass))
                {
                    $_SESSION['userSession'] = $userRow['userID'];
                     $_SESSION['user_name'] = $userRow['userName'];
                    return true;
                }
                else
                {
                    header("Location: index.php?error");
                    exit;
                }
            }
            else
            {
                header("Location: index.php?inactive");
                exit;
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            header("Location: index.php?error");
            exit;
        }       
    }
    catch(PDOException $ex)
    {
        echo $ex->getMessage();
    }
}
```

**logout.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user = new USER();

if(!$user->is_logged_in())
{
    $user->redirect($web);
}

if($user->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user->logout();    
    $user->redirect($web);
}
$url = $web;
if(isset($_GET["session_expired"])) {
    $url .= "?session_expired=" . $_GET["session_expired"];
}
header("Location:$url");
?>
```

**login.php**

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once 'class.user.php';
$user_login = new USER();

if($user_login->is_logged_in()!="")
{
    $user_login->redirect($web.$_SESSION['user_name']);
}

if(isset($_POST['btn-login']))
{
    $uname = trim($_POST['txtuname']);
    $upass = trim($_POST['txtupass']);

    if($user_login->login($uname,$upass))
    {
        $user_login->redirect($uname);
    }
}
?>
```

But my code is not working! How can I sort out my problem?

Comment: not working ? can you describe ?

Comment: No, it does not show any error! It does not work only.

Comment: Please make error reporting on, I think its help you for code debuging: 
ini_set("display_errors", "1");
error_reporting(E_ALL);

Comment: So logout is not working but you didn't show the `logout` method of `User`

Comment: You don't set `loggedin_time` on login. Do you set it somewhere else? In `isLoginSessionExpired` method you check if `loggedin_time` is set. But do you actually set it?

Comment: The problem is `isset($_SESSION["userSession"])` is `true` even if `$_SESSION["userSession"]` is set to `false`. Use `unset($_SESSION["userSession"])`

Comment: @Dmitry so I should set `loggedin_time` . Where to set on `login.php` or `home.php`? And my `loggedin_time` code would be `$_SESSION['loggedin_time'] = time(); `, am I right?

Comment: @DanMiller can you please put your answer with changes in the code.

Comment: @Chiru will you  described what exactly issue are you getting? After expiration does it redirect to `logout.php`?

Comment: @B.Desai It also does not go to `logout.php`. It stays there only after refreshing page without any activity go 15 secs.

Comment: Can you please show the `login` method of `USER`

Comment: @ChiragJain I edited the question by adding `login` method of `USER`

Comment: I don't get it: If the session expires the user won't be logged in any more. This is the reason why you use sessions at all.

Answer (score 1):

The problem in `User`'s `logout()` method.

Since if you do `$_SESSION['userSession'] = false;` the `isset($_SESSION["userSession"])` will still give you `true`. So in class.user.php it should be:

```
public function logout(){
    session_destroy();
    unset($_SESSION['userSession']);
}
```

Comment: It didn't help me out.

Comment: @Chiru: merely stating that something did not work is so unhelpful, for someone trying to help you, that you might get a downvote as a result. Please try to avoid the phrases "it didn't help" or "it didn't work" entirely. Instead, be as detailed as you can about **how it did not work**. What errors did you get? What output did you get? What observations can you supply to help someone help you move forward?